# Database Replication from 1 server to 5 servers

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 5 servers and in that, i am inserting and changing the database in 1 server through the C# application and now what I want is, those all changes should be updated in all 5 servers. I am using MySQL free version as my database kindly help me doing this

Comment: Far too broad. Start by googling for ways to replicate your MySQL database. Then maybe hire a DBA or technical engineer if you want to make a good job of it.

Answer (score -3):

try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string query = null;
        string db1 = "Server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database1=crudasp;";
        string db2 = "Server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database2=crudasp;";
        string db3 = "Server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database3=crudasp;";
        string db4=  "Server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database4=crudasp;";
        string db5 = "Server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database5=crudasp;";

        public class DbConnection
        {
            public MySqlConnection MyConn = new MySqlConnection(query);
            public MySqlCommand MyCommand;
            public MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            public MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter;
        }

        DbConnection dbConn = new DbConnection();

        void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("input your query");
            string queryinput = Console.ReadLine();
            loop(queryinput);

        }

        public void loop( string queryinputx)
        {
            query = null;
            int x = 0;
            if (x == 1)
                query = db1;
            else if (x == 2)
                query = db2;
            else if (x == 3)
                query = db3;
            else if (x == 4)
                query = db4;
            else if (x == 5)
                query = db5;

            while (x < 5)
            {
                try
                {
                    string SQL =  queryinputx;
                    dbConn.MyConn.Open();
                    dbConn.MyCommand = new MySqlCommand(SQL, dbConn.MyConn);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    dbConn.MyConn.Close();
                }
                x++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. **This code doesn't even work. Here is why:** There will be no database connection, because the connection string is not send to the `MySqlConnection` instance (it will be `null` when called); the query won't get executed, because nobody tells the `MySqlCommand` to do so. The `x = 0` doesn't really make any sense and the if statements in `loop` won't get executed.